# Gheed is abusing my addiction. What are my odds when gambling in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

So, I've just picked up D2 again to play with a friend, and we both have been giving that jovial fellow Gheed the majority (read: all) of our money for the chance of decent items.

What is the chance of getting rare/set/unique items from the various gambling merchants throughout the acts?

Comment: omg why did you mention this! im going to have to go play it again now!

Comment: That's basically what happened to me, it spreads like crazy. Watch out sheeple!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the all-knowing [Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/basics/gambling.shtml)

> The items you receive will be from most common, to most rare: Magic
>   Items, Rare, Sets, Uniques. Set and Unique Items are extremely rare.
>   The chance for Uniques is 1 in 2,000 (0.05%) and 1 in 1,000 (0.10%)
>   for Sets. The chance for Rares is 1 in 10 (10%). Magic Items are
>   1/~1.1 (89.85%).

Comment: Oh wow, it has been like 8 years since I've seen that site. I had completely forgotten about it, I wish I could give another upvote for reminding me of it.

Comment: I could be mis-remembering, but wasn't there supposed to be one rare, set or unique item per visit to gambling? It's been a while since I played, but I recall using the strategy of going in with enough money to buy everything to be guaranteed one special item and selling back all the blues.

Comment: @Edsobo I don't remember ever hearing that.  It sounds like an urban legend that would be difficult to disprove since you are unlikely to have enough money to buy everything, and you would get a rare 1 out of 10 items anyways.  So odds are buying everything would get you multiple rares.

Comment: @bwarner Sounds like I have a new weekend project to add to my list... :)

Comment: @edsobo; The Diablo Wiki has info on that theory -- `Buying everything in a gambling screen does not improve the odds of getting higher quality items. There was a bug in early versions of Diablo II that made one item on every gambling page unique, but this was fixed in a patch long ago.` http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Gambling

Comment: @Molomby The majority of my time with Diablo II was pre-expansion, so that may be what I'm remembering.